# Strange Font Behaviour On HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have this code to draw some text on my HTML Canvas :

```
$("#canvastext").keyup(function(){              
ctx.lineWidth  = 8;
ctx.font = '20pt Arial';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';

var text = document.getElementById('canvastext').value;

text = text.toUpperCase();
x = canvas.width/2;
y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
});
```

But why some characters have this strange shape :

[image: html canvas font issue]

Why `A`, `M,` `V`, `W` have ugly stroke lines?

Comment: A `fiddle` would be much helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `linejoin` property in `canvas` is default to `miter`, and when the line join angle is smaller, it'll create a sharper join at the point, which will extend longer.
Solution:

1. Set `ctx.miterLimit`, like `ctx.miterLimit=1`.
2. Use other `lineJoin` value, like `round`, `

```js
var canvas =  document.getElementById('cv');
var canvas2 =  document.getElementById('cv2');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
$("#canvastext").keyup(function(){              
     ctx.lineWidth  = 8;
     ctx.font = '20pt Arial';
     ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
     ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
     ctx.textAlign = 'center';
     ctx.miterLimit = 2;
    
     ctx2.lineWidth  = 8;
     ctx2.font = '20pt Arial';
     ctx2.strokeStyle = 'black';
     ctx2.fillStyle = 'white';
     ctx2.textAlign = 'center';
     ctx2.lineJoin = 'round';
     
     var text = document.getElementById('canvastext').value;
     text = text.toUpperCase();
     x = canvas.width/2;
     y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
     ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
    
     x = canvas2.width/2;
     y = canvas2.height - canvas.height/4.5;
     ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx2.strokeText(text, x, y);
     ctx2.fillText(text, x, y);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="canvastext"/><br/>
<canvas id="cv" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
<canvas id="cv2" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `shadow*`, instead of `stroke*`:

```
ctx.textBaseline = “top”
ctx.shadowColor = “#000”
ctx.shadowOffsetX = width;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
ctx.shadowBlur = blur;
ctx.fillText(text, -width, 0);
```